# Memory management issue in google map IOS

Tags: google-maps, memory-management, ios8, autorelease

I'am working on a Locate app, using google map to locate. And the issue is; our app consumes huge amount of memory while i'am doing anything on a map like zoom in or zoom out or while plotting marker on map and it is not releasing the memory. It is really a trouble, i have searched all over and in SO also but didn't find any proper solution. Someone says to to do these stuffs:

```
        self.mapView.delegate = nil;
        [self.mapView clear];
        [self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.mapView stopRendering];     //Deprecated in ios8
```

tried all of the above codes except last line which is deprecated in `IOS8`, but no use. I'am sure there'll be solution since lot of similar famous apps are there in Appstore which are working cool. Hope some one expert in this can help me.

Comment: why do you mean by `not releasing`, how you check the marker is `not releasing`. You can try remove marker from the `mapView`. Also where do you call the above lines?

Comment: @ztan: i mean, they all not releasing the allocated memory.

Comment: @MumthezirVP have you found any solution..? me too facing the same issue. tried everything.. memory get's removed only if mapview is removed from superview.